# Soundtouch class not working now

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

There is great library for realtime pith shifting https://github.com/also/soundtouch-as3

If was work fine until Jule 2015 (at this time was discovered another Adobe Flash Player zero-day (assigned with CVE number, CVE-2015-5123))

Is there anybody successfully use this library? I can't debug this ... because of I know AS3 not so well, maybe anybody know the reason of this

Answer (score 1):

it's not an solution to this but after a similar issue I ended up using the Sonoport libraries instead. They're worth checking out as have some cutting edge algorithms and do realtime manipulation of pitch / rate etc.

www.sonoport.com

I've made the swc available [here](http://www.visualife.co.uk/downloads/SonoportCollection.swc) as it looks like their downloads aren't currently available

Comment: Looks good, http://sonoport.com/manual/ But I can't find link to swc library (SonoportCollection.swc)

Comment: @DimaMelnik looks like they've updated their website, for now I've put a download link into the answer and will update this post once I find their new download section.

Comment: What I do wrong? 
_mp3PlayerSnd = new MP3PlayerSound();
_mp3PlayerSnd.audioFile = "http_url_link.mp3";
_mp3PlayerSnd.play();
I see http get йнукн to server for this file but not playing anything. How to start playing?

Comment: @DimaMelnik, if you open another question then you can paste your code and I can look into this properly. I'll also be able to look a my source tomorrow morning to compare.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32379566/sonoport-how-to-play-audio-actionscript